# gatsby-plugin-mdx superscript and subscript support

Tags: gatsby

I'm having trouble getting some HTML elements like `<sup>` and `<sub>` to work with `gatsby-plugin-mdx`.

I found the following code in the gatsby-plugin-mdx documentation. You can add native remark plugins to gatsby-plugin-mdx like this:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-mdx/#md-plugins

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        remarkPlugins: [require("remark-abbr")],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Along those lines I added `remark-sub-super` to my project and put it in my gatsby-config like so:

```js
const remarkSubSuper = require('remark-sub-super');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
        remarkPlugins: [remarkSubSuper],
    },
  ],
}
```

Despite this, I'm still seeing some errors that look like they have something to do with `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags.

```sh
"gatsby-plugin-mdx" threw an error while running the onCreateNode lifecycle:

unknown: Unterminated JSX contents (17:16)

  15 | <em><sup>1 </sup>https://example.com/</em>
  16 | <em><sup>2 </sup>https://example.com/</em>
> 17 |     </MDXLayout>
     |                 ^
  18 |   )
  19 | };
  20 | MDXContent.isMDXComponent = true/<PATH>: unknown: Unterminated JSX contents (17:16)

  15 | <em><sup>1 </sup>https://example.com/</em>
  16 | <em><sup>2 </sup>https://example.com/</em>
> 17 |     </MDXLayout>
     |                 ^
  18 |   )
  19 | };
  20 | MDXContent.isMDXComponent = true
```

Some version information:

```
"gatsby": "^2.19.18",
"gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^1.0.73",
"remark-sub-super": "^1.0.19",
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Check for unclosed tags in your component.

Comment: For a bit of background, I'm mass exporting pages from WordPress into Markdown files. So each Markdown file is made up of valid HTML. To be sure, I ran some of the pages in which I'm seeing these errors through a partial HTML validator and they checked out. I also checked them manually for unclosed tags and couldn't find any.

Comment: Also the formatting gets all messed up in the error log above around the <sup>1</sup>. You can’t really see the messed-upness in the github formatted version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed the formatting of the HTML being fed to `gatsby-plugin-mdx`.

Apparently `<img />` tags need to be closed. After closing the image tags, I needed to go into the markdown files that were throwing errors and inspect the HTML manually. Since this content came from WordPress, some of the formatting was a bit problematic. For example, this:

```
<blockquote>How
you
doin</blockquote>
```

Would become this after running through the Markdown processor:

```
<blockquote>How
<p>you</p>
<p>doin</blockquote></p>
```